# Get user session using SQL hash ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any query usefull in finding the user details for particular SQL hash id.

I need get user name , session id, program, hostname, machine etc and other details to get

Comment: You mean, who is currently running an SQL with such SQL hash ID?

Comment: Look at sp_who. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql

Comment: Grab a copy of Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive ( http://whoisactive.com) and/or Brent Ozar's sp_BlitzWho (http://FirstResponderKit.org)

Comment: Radim, Sean and Jason - Thanks for reply . SQL is not running now, but yes it is used to run at some specific time from application and get closed quickly, hence i never caught it. Is there any way around i can get all details related to SQL owner and machine/ server etc. details for SQL HASH id i do have now.